# How to get component data? How to access the components from the outside?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I derive the component:

```
<my-component> </my-component>
```

The question is how to get the properties of this particular component, knowing only its tag "my-component"?

A more detailed description of the problem:
Using the vue-cli-service build --target wc --name my-component my-component.vue command, I compile in js file

Then I connect this script in the header of the site.

Then I use the   component

But how to get the properties of this component now and generally how to access this component? How to get the input field value in this component?

Sorry, I probably didn’t explain it well.

I need something like this:

```
<my-component id="my-component"> </my-component>
<script>
let inputValue = $("#my-component").find("input").val();//but this not work
</script>
```

Or

```
<script>
let props = <my-component></my-component>// this component props
</script>
```

In the my-component.vue file, this code:

```
<template>
    <input :placeholder="test" type="text" name="test" value="">
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'MyInputComponent',
        props: {
            placeholder: {
                type: String,
                default: "00"
            }
        },
        data () {
            return {
            }
        },

    }
</script>
```

Comment: You would need v-model binding, check this here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Text

Comment: Make sure your component finishes rendering before you select with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

usage

```
    <template>
        <input :placeholder="placeholder" type="text" @input="emitInputValue">
    </template>

    <script>
        export default {
            name: 'MyInputComponent',
            props: {
                placeholder: {
                    type: String,
                    default: "00"
                }
            },
            methods: {
              emitInputValue ($event) {
              this.$emit('input', $event.target.value)
              }
           }

        }
    </script>

get value
<my-component @input"getValue"> </my-component>

methods: {
 getValue (payload) {
  console.log(payload)
 }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I probably didn’t explain it well.

I need something like this:

<my-component> </my-component> 
let inputValue = $("#my-component").find("input").val()

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
    <input :placeholder="test" :id="id" type="text" name="test" value="">
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'MyInputComponent',
        props: {
            placeholder: {
                type: String,
                default: "00"
            },
            id: {
                type: String 
            }
        },
        data () {
            return {
            }
        },

    }
</script>
```

Now your id would be available and you can do whatever you want.

Only one suggestion i would like to give is: when you are using vue.js then try avoiding jquery for getting input value. there are many ways in vue.js itself you can get input text value.

Let me know if you need something else